# How can I use different properties for the same component using Styled Component for React JS?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

For example for same component at some places I want to use `border` while at other places `border-bottom`

How can I achieve this?

Also can anyone please tell me what this code in styled component means:

```
color: ${prop('theme.color.blue', '#0F0F3A')};
```

Comment: if you read the docs, the answer is right there. https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: But I am not doing something like that color : white or blue but womething like whether I should use color or background-color as explained in my example.

The doc example that you linked will help me change border thickness dynamically but I am looking to use either brder or border-bottom in same component, they are not same thing.

I have no idea why you got to be so rude though.

Comment: Btw for now I am using something like ```styled(myComponent)``` to overwrite the css property but I feel like its not a good solution as I have to do the same thing in a bunch of locations i.e. I am repeating myself.

Comment: Then that has nothing got to do with styled component or props.

Comment: If you think so then flag it and ask a moderator to take action, rather than being toxic here. I am using Styled component to style, I am facing a styling issue ergo to me it is a styled component issue, I may be wrong and there can be a better approach and I am happy to learn that but if you don't have an answer please don't bother to response. 

But if you had read the question, you wouldn't be commenting.

Comment: per first comment, answer is in the doc about props + styled components, if you bother reading. You can achieve what you want just by using props like what the doc recommend you doing.

Comment: Is this Schrodinger's styled component? Sometimes it has nothing to do with props and styled component and sometimes just read about props + styled component?

Can you read what you yourself are witting?

Comment: did you read and try? -> https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-breeze-g71t2?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Each properties can take 4 values. Set width to 0 if you don't want the border.

```css
div {
 padding: 20px;
 border-style: solid dashed dotted solid;
 border-width: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
 border-color: blue yellow green red;
}
```

```html
<div> I AM A DIV</div>
```